# error de compilación con icc en VisualStudio

Tags: c, visual-studio

Actualmente estoy acoplando varias librerías externas escritas en `C` a un código propio (también en `C`) y me estoy encontrando con dificultades a la hora de compilar con `ICC` en **VisualStudio**.

El código compila perfectamente con `GCC` en **Linux**, pero también necesito obligatoriamente compilarlo desde **VisualStudio**. Me estoy encontrando errores de este tipo:

> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "int * Nlinks"
>   (?Nlinks@@3PAHA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "struct TPattern *
>   Pattern" (?Pattern@@3PEAUTPattern@@EA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "double RunoffError"
>   (?RunoffError@@3NA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "struct TDivider *
>   Divider" (?Divider@@3PEAUTDivider@@EA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "int DryStep"
>   (?DryStep@@3HA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "int SweepEnd"
>   (?SweepEnd@@3HA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "int SweepStart"
>   (?SweepStart@@3HA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "struct TOutlet * Outlet"
>   (?Outlet@@3PEAUTOutlet@@EA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "int RouteModel"
>   (?RouteModel@@3HA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "int InfilModel"
>   (?InfilModel@@3HA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "double OldRoutingTime"
>   (?OldRoutingTime@@3NA) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "struct TAdjust Adjust"
>   (?Adjust@@3UTAdjust@@A) en peka2d_interface.obj
>
> 2>p2dGUI.obj : error LNK2005: ya se definió "double ReportTime"
>   (?ReportTime@@3NA) en peka2d_interface.obj

...

y así sucesivamente.

Agradecería cualquier sugerencia que me ayude a localizar el problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Con qué comando o Makefile compilas?

Comment: Para compilar el proyecto desde VisualStudio utilizo la configuración Release con la plataforma x64.

Answer (score 0):

No disponemos de las cabeceras, pero todo apunta a que tanto en `p2dGUI` como en `peka2d_interface` tienes declarados / implementados los mismos elementos:

```
int * NLinks;

struct TPattern * Pattern;

double RunoffError;

struct TDivider * Divider;

int DryStep;

// ...
```

Evita los nombres duplicados o usa `extern` convenientemente para evitar las duplicidades.